# ftp server to restrict 'get' and 'ls'

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I would like to configure ftp server in such a way that no client can use get and ls
command 
Is it possible to do it ftp server configuration or can we go for round around method 
pls guide me

I have googled it and found no straight forward configuration to do this

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Found that dirlist_enable=NO , can disable the ls command , pls let me know how to restrict get command

Comment: What kind of service this FTP server offers? If it is write only, you can change the permission of FTP sub-folder to 522 to achieve what you want.

Comment: @ahmad You are actually *answering* the question but you are doing it in a comment. Please consider adding your answer as an answer so this question might be closed.

Answer (score 1):

To help ahmad and Jan Wikholm close the question:
What kind of service this FTP server offers? If it is write only, you can change the permission of FTP sub-folder to 522 to achieve what you want.